# PhD in UK or PhD in Spain?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have won fully funded Ph.D. positions one in the UK and the other one is in Spain. 
UK job position offers me a job as a teaching assistant in addition to Ph.D., however, I would have a fellowship (research assistant) in Spain?

Ph.D. is itself is a big commitment and requires focus and hard work. I want to choose something with which I can focus on my studies as much as I can. Yet, on the other hand, I want to have professional experience in academia for further career development.

I have to choose one now and I am not sure which one would be better in the long run?

Suggestions would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Do it in the country with the language you want to work in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you a straight answer to this question. It will depend on many factors, which only you can really answer:

- Do you prefer to live in UK or Spain, and also the city in particular both countries are big and diverse.
- The research groups involved and/or the research project (this also includes obviously the supervisor)
- The details of the position (salary, possible benefits, etc.)

I probably missed other important factor but the point is this is a personal decision where no one but you will have enough information to answer.

Comment: Although this answer did not answer the question directly, it does provide the points that need to be considered (may be incomplete, though). Thus, I am upvoting.

Comment: Of these criteria, I would say that the second is by far the most important one.

Comment: @AlexB. For many, the most important one is the first.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano: fair enough. I suppose it depends on how deeply one immerses oneself in research.

Comment: Thank you so much all.